# Adding FbFlipper in Android Project gives build error = processDebugManifest > Manifest merger failed

Tags: java, android, performance, android-manifest, fbflipper

I have added **[FbFlipper](https://github.com/facebook/flipper)** Metrics. I am getting this error.

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>       /home/user/Git/my-project/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
>       Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:21:583-76:18 to override.
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>       * What went wrong:
>       Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:21:583-76:18 to override.

**For More Information:**

I have added FbFlipper Metrics library as: In build.gradle under dependencies:

```
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.22.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0'
```

And if i comment/remove the above mentioned lines from build.gradle. Project build successfully and runs fine on device.

But if i add these lines to add FbFlipper. It gives build error.

Keeping in View i have no duplicate activity names in Android Manifest. Also i have updated compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 which resolves my earlier issue which was:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Android resource linking failed

Now i'll appreciate any help in this regard, Point me where i am wrong. how to make FbFlipper metrics working in android project. Thanks in advance

**My Environment details:**

- Gradle Version: 5.0
- compileSdkVersion 28
- Android Plugin Version: 3.3.0
- FbFlipper Metrics Library Version: 0.22.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this error by Migrating all support libraries to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

You can do it as:

In gradle.build (app) add sdkVersion as 28:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    ......
    targetSdkVersion 28
    ......
}
```

Also add these implementations to migrate to androidx :-

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Then add these below two lines to gradle.properties:-

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

---

You can also do that from android studio in automated format.

- From the top bar menu in Android Studio
- Click on Refactor
- Then from Dropdown list. Click on 'Migrate to AndroidX'